# Faster algorithms for convex hulls

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming, polyhedra, polytopes, convex-hulls

I was interested in the following:

Given two polyhedra $P_1, P_2$  specified in the form:

$$ P_1 = \{x : A_1x \le b_1 \} $$ 
$$ P_2 = \{x : A_2x \le b_2 \} $$

Whereas $x \in R^n$ and $b_1, b_2$ are real vectors of same "height" dimension as $P_1$ and $P_2$ respectively.

How does one determine the convex hull $C$ of these two polyhedra. Given in the form

$$ C = \{ x : Qx \le \tau \} $$

Whereas $Q, \tau$ should be the minimum number of inequalities necessary to specify the set.

I had posted this question on [OR Exchange](https://www.or-exchange.org/questions/12714/how-to-determine-cuts-for-convex-hull), which recommended Fourier-Motzkin elimination in conjunction with a simple scheme for including every-point in the hull.

My one qualm is this doubled the number of variables. And running Fourier-Motzkin would take exponential time to reduce the "excess" variables.

Is there a procedure that that doesn't take exponential time which maintains the same number of variables?

Comment: Why would you be concerned about doubling the number of variables? It wouldn't surprise me to find that standard LP presolvers have theoretically exponential worst-case performance; but if that is the case, it just indicates that exponential complexity ought not be an automatic disqualifier, because they do work well in practice.

Comment: The convex hull. In the same number of dimensions, for the two polyhedra has number of (n-1) dimensional facets that is polynomially bounded on the number if (n-1) dimensional facets of the original two polyhedra.  To eliminate the doubling of variables back to the original n, results in exponential amount of facets (many of which become redundant), I find it, at least odd that the convex hull, which isn't by itself very complex in MY formulation, needs an EXPTIME worst case algorithm.

Comment: @MichaelGrant so hence I am curious and hopeful if in this specific application a polynomial time hull generating algorithm exists. Where the hull is given as a system of inequalities

Comment: Well, the problem is that correct algorithms have to handle not just problems like yours which "isn't by itself very complex" but also ones that are! The exponential-time simplex algorithm for LP, for instance, rarely consumes exponential time in practice, but we know that it will for *certain* problems. Thus is the conundrum.

Comment: Please know, I voted your question up, I think it's a very interesting one. I just don't think your *theoretical* objectives will be satisfied. My suspicion however is that a practical implementation will work just fine for you, even if it is not theoretically tractable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot avoid an exponential blow-up in the number of resulting constraints.

As an example, let us look at cross-polytope $P_3$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is the convex hull of all vertices obtained by all permutations of $(\pm1,0,\dots,0)$. Hence, it has $2n$ vertices and $2^n$ facets (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-polytope) and its $\mathcal{H}$-representation $Qx \leq \tau$ has at least $2^n$ rows. On the other hand, the two simplices $P_1$ and $P_2$, where 
$$P_1 = conv\{(0,\dots,0), (1,0,\dots,0), (0,1,0,\dots,0), \dots, (0,\dots,0,1)\}$$
$$P_2 = conv\{(0,\dots,0), (-1,0,\dots,0), (0,-1,0,\dots,0), \dots, (0,\dots,0,-1)\},$$
have $n+1$ vertices and also $n+1$ facets. Hence, their (minimal) $\mathcal{H}$-representations $A_1x \leq b_1$ and $A_2x \leq b_2$ have $n+1$ rows each. It is crucial to note that the convex hull of $P_1$ and $P_2$ is exactly the cross-polytope $P_3$. This shows that in your setting (unless I missed something about the "specific application") it is impossible to have a procedure which does not take exponential time at worst.

Comment: Great answer. Of course, the cross-polytope, being just the unit ball of the $\ell_1$ norm, can readily be represented using $O(n)$ inequalities *if you are allowed to introduce additional variables*. For instance, introducing $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we have: $$-y_i \leq x_i \leq y_i, \quad i=1,2,\dots,n,\quad \sum_i y_i \leq 1$$

Comment: Thanks, Michael. BTW: I like the idea of introducing additional variables and solving the problems by means of linear programs afterwards. Often you don't need the actual $\mathcal{H}$-representation.

Comment: That's right, it all depends on the underlying purpose for building the inequalities!

Comment: so this is intriguing... there are explicit cases where raising the dimension of the system, even if representing the same object, results in a more compact $\mathcal{H}$ representation

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think you will find a guaranteed fast algorithm, as the problem appears intractable in general, if I understand the below paper correctly. A quick search led me to, e.g.,

> On the Hardness of Computing Intersection, Union and Minkowski Sum of
>   Polytopes, by Hans Raj Tiwary