# Is there a way to determine if the Convex Hull of two polyhedra is going to be huge?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming, computational-geometry

So in this post:

[Faster Algorithms for Convex Hulls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412452/faster-algorithms-for-convex-hulls)

I was interested in determining if a convex hull of two $n$ dimensional polyhedra can be computed quickly, and the answer was in general: no, since for certain pairs of polyhedra the number of facets in the hull grows exponentially with the number of facets of the original constituents.

Now a natural question that follows is, given two polyhedra is it possible to estimate how many facets will be on their convex hull? What about how many facets up to a multiplicative factor $\epsilon$ of accuracy?

### Ideas:

I'm really lost as far as techniques go. As the post revealed, two very innocent looking n-simplexes if placed in the right orientation can send you to $2^n$ facets, yet in another orientation result in only $2n$ facets, both almost equally spaced. It seems that once you know the shape and orientation of the pair, understanding how they are located w.r.t each other plays a crucial rule in determining the facet count.

Comment: One way to think of a convex hull is to see it as a collection of hyperplanes cutting it out from an infinite volume chunk. The orientation issue is threefold: a rotation around the axis formed by the centroids of the polytopes; and the orientation of each polytope. Of these, the axis is intriguing. One approach might be to project each polytope onto a hyperplane perpendicular to that axis, form the convex hull (on the hyperplane), and examine the properties of the hyperplanes defining this "hypercylinder". It won't get you near any multiplicative factor, but might work as a starting point.